# Term for shortening foreign phrases in a way that would be absurd in the language of their origin

Tags: single-word-requests, foreign-phrases

The following sometimes happens in the development of English language.

A phrase from a foreign language is imported into English. English speakers find the phrase useful, but long and cumbersome. They deal with it by dropping a part of it, and so reducing it to what seems to them to be a more manageable length. The dropped part is, however, essential to the meaning that the phrase has in the language of its origin; the shortened form of the phrase thus has a very different meaning in that language, or, sometimes, no meaning at all. In English, the shortened form of the phrase nevertheless continues to be used with the same meaning as the original, full-length one; that becomes established as its meaning in English.

*Caffè latte* thus became *latte* (even though in Italian that is a word for [unadorned] milk), *chef de cuisine* became *chef* (which is, in French, a term for somebody who heads an organisation of any kind, including those that have nothing to do with food preparation), *maître d'hôtel* became *maître d'* (literally 'master of', an incomplete expression), *chaise longue* became, at least in American English, *chaise*, and *obiter dicta* became *dicta*. An older example of what is essentially the same phenomenon can be seen in the shortening of *omnibus* to *bus* (which is, in Latin, a dative-forming suffix with no independent meaning).

Is there a term for this kind of a phenomenon? Note that the question is specifically about this shortening of foreign phrases, not about the broader phenomenon of foreign words acquiring in English different meanings from the ones they have in their languages of origin.

Comment: It's often called just _shortening_ or _clipping_, but it isn't limited to foreign phrases or words. We do the same thing with English words or phrases if they get used very often. Since English never has quite the same sounds or words as the borrowed chunk, it's inevitable that it will be changed, sometimes greatly, when English speakers try to pronounce it. They will eventually settle on something (or several somethings, depending on where one lives and speaks), but it might not resemble the original much.

Comment: I've never heard *dicta* used instead of *obiter dicta*. But typically we shorten things because why say three words when one will do? And why say four syllables (*chef de cuisine*) when one (*chef*) will do? And if everyone is doing it ... well, "when in Rome ..."

Comment: @Robusto, re *dicta* see [What is the legal meaning of “in dicta”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/519608/). One syllable (*chef*) 'will do', but only if one forces oneself to forget what its original meaning is, or one has never known it to begin with—that makes this kind of a phenomenon rather different from various garden-variety shortenings of English phrases. In any event, I am not trying to start a debate on whether this kind of a phenomenon is to be welcomed or deplored (that would a matter of opinion), but merely asking whether it has received a label in linguistic theory.

Comment: @jsw29: Then I would take Professor of Linguistics Lawler's word that it's called *shortening* or *clipping*.

Comment: @Robusto, Professor Lawler's comment, I take it, implies that there is **no specific** term for this kind of shortening/clipping. Fair enough, that, combined with the absence of other answers from comparably qualified people, may well be the answer.

Comment: I always find it odd when people talk about a _head chef_, since I know that _chef (de cuisine)_ means a head cook in French!

Comment: @Laurel, I would prefer not to say *nonsensical*, as the shortened forms do have a definite sense in English; they are jarring only to those who are aware of their meaning in the language of origin.

Comment: Non-etymological? (Eh, doesn't really fit either.)

Comment: Calling the head of a kitchen a *chef* seems reasonable, and to require no more mental gymnastics than calling someone with command over 120 or so soldiers a *major*, or having several distinct uses of the word *captain* (a minor army rank, a much greater naval rank, a familiar term for a boss similar to "guvner", and various metaphorical uses...). Words shift, expand, or specialise their meanings all the time.

Comment: For what its worth, the short form of *obiter dictum/a* is not *dicta*: it is "*obiter*": -- 1993 *With respect, however, to overseas trading transactions it is clear from..the obiter in IRC v Frere (1964) 42 TC 125 that one looks to the net trading income.* P. C. Soares, Non-resident Trusts 74Citation details. -- Indeed, the "obiter" part is the important part.

Comment: There are all kinds of chefs in a restaurant. The terminology is apparently the same in the U S and France. https://www.culinaryschools.org/chef-types/#context/api/listings/prefilter

Comment: @Greybeard, *dicta* appears by itself **very** often; see the question cited above in this thread of comments.

Comment: In 40 years of reading judgements, I can't recall seeing it. Is it AE?

Comment: @Greybeard, yes, it is more common in the US than elsewhere, but it can be found outside the US as well.

Answer (score 4):

In a comment John Lawler wrote:

> It's often called just *shortening* or *clipping*, but it isn't limited to foreign phrases or words. We do the same thing with English words or phrases if they get used very often. Since English never has quite the same sounds or words as the borrowed chunk, it's inevitable that it will be changed, sometimes greatly, when English speakers try to pronounce it. They will eventually settle on something (or several somethings, depending on where one lives and speaks), but it might not resemble the original much.

As shortening/clipping is a concept that covers much more than what is described in the question, Professor Lawler's comment implies that there is **no specific term** for that phenomenon.

Comment: Some comments under the question seem to assume that every Anglophone who uses, say, ***chef*** or ***maître d'*** does or should know that it's "short" for ***chef de cuisine*** or ***maître d'hôtel***. But of course, that's not how it works - all that matters is the initial syllable[s] aren't an existing word, so there's no scope for confusion. And you don't need to *know* a foreign language to make use of a few "Anglicized" foreign expressions. Who cares if what's left after shortening isn't "idiomatic / valid" in its original language, once it's become incorporated into *our* language?

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I don't think that anybody assumes that; indeed the shortening is probably initiated precisely by those who don't speak the language from which the phrase is imported. And it's true that, in so far as one's aim is to communicate successfully in English (e.g. to get a latte), it doesn't matter that the phrase means something else in another language. Such shortenings are nevertheless jarring to those who **do** understand the language of the phrase's origin, and  I suspect that, at least initially, they are reluctant to use them.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible word for shortening a word or a saying in a language other than English is the word ***elliptical***. From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/de%20gustibus):

> de gustibus, de gus·​ti·​bus, dēˈgəstəbəs, dāˈgu̇stē bu̇s :

> concerning
> taste. "I still detest the sound of him, but *de gustibus*"— Jean Stafford
> —used ***elliptically*** for its full Latin original or its translation [my emphasis]

The full saying in Latin should be: ***De gustibus non est disputandum***