# Why is the word "cello" pronounced with CH /tʃ/ and not S?

Tags: pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling

I have always been pronouncing the word "cello" and "ciao" with a /s/ sound but today I found out that they were actually /tʃ/ ⟨ch⟩.

It is **/ˈtʃɛloʊ/** and **/ˈtʃaʊ/**. The letter C gives /tʃ/ sound rather than /s/ (which is what it should give before E and I). Almost all other words in which C comes before the letter E and I give /s/ sound. Examples: cell, fence, cent, city etc., the only common exception is "Celt" which has a /k/ sound.

I searched my question on Google and it gave me some similar questions in other platforms.

[Same question on Quora](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-c-in-cello-pronounced-as-t%CA%83-other-than-the-commonly-found-s#:%7E:text=happens%20in%20English.-,If%20we%27re%20to%20be%20more%20spefic%20with%20this%20individual,pretty%20easy%20for%20English%20speakers):

One answer on Quora says:

> It comes from Italian, and in Italian spelling, a c in front of an e or i is pronounced /tʃ/" but we have many other words that are from Italian in which the C comes before E and yet it gives /s/ sound like "concert" and some other.

It didn't convince me.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cello) was also of no help.

So why is it pronounced with ⟨ch⟩ /tʃ/ and not /s/ ⟨s⟩?

**Note:** I know that English spelling is weird and does not represent English pronunciation but things have causes and reasons. I just want to know what "caused" it.

Comment: [Italian–Learn to pronounce Consonant C: CI/CE - CHI/CHE...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ueia5n1LvY8)

Comment: **Why** exactly did the answer you found on Quora fail to convince you?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112773/discussion-on-question-by-sphinx-why-is-the-word-cello-pronounced-with-ch-t).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[*Cello*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-cello#Italian) comes from Italian where it's pronounced with /t͡ʃ/.

*Concert* comes from French where it's pronounced with /s/, *concerto* comes from Italian where it's pronounced with /t͡ʃ/.

According to [*Standford University Website*](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Ejrb/reference/italian.html), the letter *c* in Italian is pronounced /t͡ʃ/ when it's followed by *i* or *e*.

Examples:

- [cello](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-cello#Italian) -> /ˈtʃɛləʊ/
- [ciao](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ciao#Italian) -> /ˈt͡ʃao/
- [concerto](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/concerto#Italian) -> /kənˈtʃəːtəʊ/ etc.

As [John Lawler](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/15299/john-lawler) says in a comment (with little changes):

> [*Concert* comes from French](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/concert#French), and gets pronounced with /s/ like French. [*Concerto* comes from Italian](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/concerto#Italian), and gets pronounced with /tʃ/ like Italian. As noted, English spelling doesn't represent English pronunciation. But French and Italian spellings **do**, and we borrowed the spellings as well as the pronunciations.

It seems to me that Italian words don't change their pronunciations in English. Other example include *pizza, palazzo, cello, crescendo, zucchini, Pinocchio* etc.

Comment: (There are a few Italian words often pronounced differently in English, such as *bruschetta* /bruːʃetə/ and *calzone* /kalzəʊn/, as well as the notorious /ekspresoʊ/; and some like *lasagne* have changed both pronunciation and spelling. Although often the Italian pronunciation is also heard from some people; English-speakers seem to do better with Italian than French.)

Answer (score 0):

The full name of the instrument is "violoncello" in both English and Italian. This word is Italian and English has imported it with the Italian pronunciation. In Italian "-cello" is a diminutive suffix, so the name means small violon (not violin). "Cello" is an English (and German) abbreviation, and preserves the pronunciation of the "c".

Comment: It is indeed [noteworthy](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/525211) that *cello* is a clipped version of *violoncello*, but how is that relevant to the pronounciation of *c*, which is what the question is about (and which is adequately explained in the already posted answer)?

Answer (score 0):

I teach Latin and have studied how to pronounce Italian. Both Latin and Italian, which comes from Latin, have rules for where the letter c makes the "ch" sound when followed by e or i.

See the following sources:

1. [Italian Pronunciation Challenge: C / CH / CC](https://dailyitalianwords.com/italian-pronunciation-challenge-c-ch-cc/)
2. [Latin language (Lingua Latina)](https://www.omniglot.com/writing/latin2.htm).
3. [Latin phonology and othography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_phonology_and_orthography)

Comment: Of course, Latin pronunciation changed vastly over the millennia...  Was "Caesar" actually pronounced "Kaiser" when Julius was living??

Comment: @GEdgar German had to get it from somewhere.

Comment: Church Latin is pronounced like modern standard Italian, but it was not always so.

Comment: @GEdgar Yes, *Caesar* in *ɢᴀɪᴠꜱ ɪᴠʟɪᴠꜱ ᴄᴀᴇꜱᴀʀ* was indeed pronounced with /k/ during his own lifetime. One reason we know this is that when he wrote it in Greek, Caesar spelled his own name *Γάιος Ιούλιος Καίσαρ* , **starting with Greek kappa** [per Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julius_Caesar#The_name_Gaius_Julius_Caesar): “In Greek, during Caesar’s time, his family name was written *Καίσαρ* (Kaísar], reflecting its contemporary pronunciation. Thus, his name is pronounced in a similar way to the pronunciation of the German *Kaiser* ([kaɪ̯zɐ]) or Dutch *keizer* [kɛizɛ].”

Comment: @GEdgar Although written ‹c› in Classical Latin was always phonemic /k/, some tiny phonetic changes occurred—completely non-phonemically—before front vowels. [Quoth Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_phonology_and_orthography#Notes_on_phonetics): “/kʷ/ and [ɡʷ] were **palatalized before a front vowel**, becoming [kᶣ] and [ɡᶣ], as in quī [kᶣiː].” Listen to sound clips there contrasting phonetic [kʷ] with phonetic [kᶣ]. Over time Latin ‹c› before front vowels became [t͡s] in trad. German pron of L., [t͡ʃ] in Italianized Church L., [θ] in std. Northern Spanish, and /s/ in French.

Comment: Harp seal, you may wish to edit this answer to improve its reception. I realize that you know this, but your posting is worded confusingly given that only in [Ecclesiastical Latin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ecclesiastical_Latin) does the pronunciation of Latin *c* before front vowels come out with the "ch" sound  (the palatalized affricate sound [t͡ʃ]) the way it is in Italian. In Classical Latin, it did not.