# What is the origin of the word "latte" referring to a caffè latte?

Tags: etymology, american-english

*Latte*, as in the usage

> I'd like a *latte* (example from *[Cambridge English Empower](https://books.google.com/books?id=lrAPBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA43&lpg=PA43&dq=%22I%27d%20like%20a%20latte%22&source=bl&ots=QzKXr--4b8&sig=ACfU3U1xoM-QIMUy62gosV1yGb3jm4o4eA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi52Ozf8I73AhVurmoFHQoqAFwQ6AF6BAg0EAM#v=onepage&q=%22I%27d%20like%20a%20latte%22&f=false)*, 2015)

is ubiquitous among English speakers who have visited coffee bars or seen them in film or TV. It means a *caffè latte*, steamed milk with espresso. Yet *latte* by itself (what would mean "milk" in Italian) is a further transformation; people understand that espresso is involved without having to say so.

Where and when did this abbreviated usage originate in English? The Oxford English Dictionary pegs the usage in 1989 and the US but doesn't provide more details (OED, "[latte, n.](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/248120)"). Someone asked a similar and now deleted question yesterday but didn't have more details.

Comment: Related: [Shortening of foreign phrases](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/525211).

Comment: Thanks for saving this question and providing a good answer. I just wonder why when I asked it it was defined as a “silly” question.

Comment: I ordered a latte in Italy once and got a glass of hot milk... ‍♂️

Comment: I had always thought this was originally a [*latte macchiato*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latte_macchiato) with much more milk to coffee than any Italian would drink a *caffè latte* - but apparently trying to trace it back to Italian coffee habits would be the wrong idea

Answer (score 16):

As a loanword from Italian, *latte* (as in *a latte*, and distinct from combined forms like *caffe latte*) is from the US, and likely the Pacific Northwest, circa the mid-to-late 1980s. (It first appears in print by itself in 1987.) This answer will first cover the OED entry, cite other early examples, and then hypothesize based on the history of coffee culture in Seattle in the 1980s that Howard Schultz may have helped popularize the drink if not the term.

### Oxford English Dictionary - when *latte* became mainstream

The OED entry for "[latte, n.1](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/248120)" gives its earliest quote from a 3 May 1989 article in the *New York Times*:

> 1989   N.Y. Times 3 May c8/4   The most common order heard is for a **latté**, espresso with milk, another variation on cappuccino and café au lait.

In general, my searches confirm that *a latte* is in widespread use by the early 1990s, and I find it plausible that the *New York Times* is one of the first national publications to pick up on the trend.

This is a case where tracing the article to its original source tells far more about the context.

### *Latte* may have emerged on the west coast

The original New York Times article from 1989 ("[DE GUSTIBUS; In Seattle, Espresso is Raised to an Art](https://www.nytimes.com/1989/05/03/garden/de-gustibus-in-seattle-espresso-is-raised-to-an-art.html)") connects the growth in espresso drinks to the emerging coffee market in Seattle. Two interviewees provide a description of a lively coffee house culture developing in Seattle starting in the 1960s and 1970s:

> Kent Bakke, owner of Visions Espresso, an importer and distributor of coffee and espresso equipment, said the quality of the coffee was a key. ''In the late 60's and early 70's we were developing our palates in Seattle,'' he said. ''All things related to food and wine - and coffee is part of it.''
>
> Debra Hackett, who is a sales manager for S.B.C., one of the city's large roasters, says her company and the other big roaster, Starbucks Coffee Company, ''have been responsible for educating the public about quality coffee, to appreciate that it is better to have one good cup than five or six poor ones.''

The reporting indirectly suggests that *latte*, like other espresso beverages, emerged within the growth of the coffee market in Seattle. My attempts to trace other sources similarly suggest *latte* is only present in west coast authors and publications but not elsewhere, indicating a possible point of origin on the west coast. Take for example "[Great tastes and scents at a no-nonsense price](https://www.proquest.com/newspapers/great-tastes-scents-at-no-nonsense-price/docview/422621966/se-2)" (July 17, 1987) in *The San Diego Union*, which reports on a local shop:

> There's no better way to greet the day than with a cup of excellent espresso or cafe latte at The Kiosk in Del Mar. This small, unassuming shop features freshly roasted beans, low prices (90 cents for an espresso; 95 cents for a **latte**), orange juice squeezed while you watch, great chocolate-chunk cookies, breakfast muffins and friendly service.

In the same year, in *The Vancouver Sun*, writer Eve Johnson reports on a place called Cafe Zen, "A breakfast place to soothe troubled souls" (16 October 1987):

> The specials seem to have been constructed on the basis of whimsy: $4.95 buys Eggs Florentine, half a grapefruit and a **latte** or cappuccino; $2.95 buys a half order of Eggs Florentine (one egg) and regular tea or coffee. You can get **latte** instead by paying the difference, and on fragile mornings, you certainly should.

Then there is Jan Grover, who worked in San Francisco in the late 1980s, writing about preferred beverages to have while reading M.F.K. Fisher (Grover, J. Z. (1989). [The Pleasures of Memory](https://doi.org/10.2307/4020502). The Women’s Review of Books, 6(9), 1–4.):

> If, like me, you prefer to choose your time and place to eat – if a **latte** or a chilled Sauternes or a Sierra Nevada on draft in the company of strangers enhances your day, makes your writing more enjoyable, then seek out the company of M.F.K. Fisher.

(Side note: Sierra Nevada Brewing, an early craft beer place, started in California in 1980, so this quote cites multiple relatively trendy beverages.) In other words, the earliest uses for *a latte* I can track (see note 1 below) all pertain to the west coast. I hypothesize the origin is still more specific: Seattle in the mid-1980s.

### *Caffe latte* and the Seattle coffee culture

First, a little history. In the 1960s and 1970s, Seattle had two kinds of shops related to coffee. The first would be the *coffee shop* or *cafe*, a sit-down restaurant focused on broadly American food and offering drip coffee to drink. The [menu for Coffee Dan's from the Seattle Public Library](https://cdm16118.contentdm.oclc.org/digital/collection/p16118coll5/id/745/rec/11), undated, in Seattle is a good example: big focus on breakfast with beverage options (coffee, tea) in small type in the bottom right. These are familiar establishments across the US. The second would be a coffee roaster. Peet's (1966) was an early specialty coffee roaster coming out of Berkeley, CA; Starbucks (1971) and other roasters soon opened up in Seattle (see ["Third wave of coffee," Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_wave_of_coffee#History)). They were focused on selling coffee beans, not brewed coffee. Nonetheless, they raised customer awareness of coffee sources and types.

By the mid-1970s, a new kind of coffee bar began to pop up in Seattle, starting with Cafe Allegro ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caf%C3%A9_Allegro)). Cafe Allegro and similar shops focused more on the types of coffee brewed. In its early menu (via [Seattle Public Library](https://cdm16118.contentdm.oclc.org/digital/collection/p16118coll5/id/16/rec/14)) one can see the differentiation of kinds of coffee like *espresso*, *cappuccino*, and *mocha*, albeit no *latte* or *caffe latte*:

[image]

Based on several fruitless searches, I'm inclined to believe that *latte* wasn't around at the time. For example, a Seattle Times article by Keming Kuo titled “[Coffeehouses: Beating the Rat Race](https://www.krabarchive.com/pdf/st-1978-02-25-otto-borsodi.pdf)” (February 25, 1978) describes many of these early coffeehouses and details offerings like a 35 cent espresso from Otto’s or a wide selection of teas, coffees, and candies at Yetta’s. Lattes are unmentioned, and I've found no other mentions from that time.

That brings the possible date for *latte* to the mid-1980s. One clue: in 1986, *Caffe latte* first appears on the menu of a small coffee bar called *Il Giornale*. The bar was opened by Howard Schultz in 1985-6 and merged with Starbucks when Schultz bought them out in 1987. The menu (also via [SPL](https://cdm16118.contentdm.oclc.org/digital/collection/p16118coll5/id/1580/rec/1)) includes the following:

> Caffe Latte
>
> (espresso and steamed milk)

How this item got on the menu may be an origin point for *latte* being used instead of *cappuccino* or *cafe au lait*, prior English terms for milk with coffee. Howard Schultz founded this coffee shop after working at Starbucks in marketing for a few years. In 1983, Schultz took a trip to Italy, where he drank his first latte (Sheila Farr, [Starbucks: The Early Years](https://historylink.org/File/20292)). By 1984 Starbucks, which had opened its first coffee bar in 1982, would include the *caffe latte* on its own menu (Starbucks Company Timeline, via [Internet Archive Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20210618154915/https://www.starbucks.com/assets/ba6185aa2f9440379ce0857d89de8412.pdf)). Schultz left to found *Il Giornale* by 1985, where he kept the drink.

*Caffe latte* may have soon spread to other establishments, and they may have also begun to adapt the term *latte* to refer to the new drink. By September 1987, the same year as the earliest newspaper articles in Vancouver and San Diego, *latte* by itself appears on the menu for an unrelated Seattle bar, *Gravity Bar* ([University of Washington Library](https://digitalcollections.lib.washington.edu/digital/collection/menus/id/942/rec/14)):

[image]

My hypothesis is that *latte* comes from the early uses of *caffe latte* in west coast coffee culture centered in Seattle and possibly from Howard Schultz himself, which is why the verifiable print dates for *a latte* in 1987 come shortly after coffee bars started selling the *caffe latte* in 1984.

### Research process

For this post I consulted several databases in an attempt to find usages of *latte* prior to 1990. My general search terms included "a latte" (more restrictive) and "latte" (less restrictive, including *caffe latte*, the last name Latte, *Latte stones*, ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latte_stone)) and so on). I skimmed results to check for pertinence and attempted to verify dates within the source if possible or with corroborating sources. The list includes:

- The [British National Corpus](https://www.english-corpora.org/bnc/) (1980s-early 1990s) - no results
- [Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a%20latte%22&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A%2Ccd_max%3A1990&tbm=bks) - unrelated results
- [JSTOR](https://www.jstor.org) - found *The Pleasures of Memory* (1989); otherwise unrelated results
- [ProQuest, News and Newspapers](https://about.proquest.com/en/content-solutions/news/) - in "Oldest First" search, first eight results in 1980s all tied to west coast publications (Los Angeles Times, Vancouver Sun, San Francisco Chronicle, Seattle Times, Orange County Register); ninth
  result is May 1989 NYT article "DE GUSTIBUS." Six remaining 1980s results are west coast.
- [Gale OneFile](https://www.gale.com/intl/c/infotrac-newsstand) - has "DE GUSTIBUS," no other results.

As part of my search strategy, I also found some results tied to library archives. That led me to search for material from digital restaurant menu collections from the [Seattle Public Library](https://spl.contentdm.oclc.org/digital/collection/p16118coll8/id/319/rec/27) as well as the [University of Washington Libraries](https://content.lib.washington.edu/menusweb/index.html), setting aside sources where the date was not verifiable. Since these sources were necessarily location-based, I ran a comparative search with another menu collection (the [New York Public Library menu collection](http://menus.nypl.org/)); the only valid result was for *caffe latte* in 1989, *[Coffee Etc.](http://menus.nypl.org/menu_pages/56008/explore)* in Tucson, AZ. Since menus are ephemeral texts, it's possible undigitized archives or unarchived material exists with earlier usage.

None of these searches turned up credible evidence for *a latte* existing beyond the west coast before 1989. That is one reason why I hypothesize usage to originate in the west coast of the US and Canada.

Comment: @jsw29  i am also surprised and disappointed that earlier instances were not found in the UK as my  family ran quite a famous Cafe in London during the late 40s until the late 70s and I know they imported the original Gaggia espresso machine from Italy. What would you suggest the OP do to verify whether the abbreviation "latte" actually began in the West Coast? Time travel is not an option.

Comment: Sadly all my aunts and uncles who ran and worked in the London snack bar (The Cathedral) have all died. So there is no one left to ask if the shop sold "caffe latte" or simply translated it as milk coffee.

Comment: My guess, @Mari-LouA, would be that they served *café au lait*.

Comment: @jsw29 The shortening seems to me like an obvious progression that could easily have happened in multiple places independently as soon as the full name became established. People know that "caffe" (and "café") in names of drinks means "coffee", so the rest of the phrase must be the _type_ of coffee. So, "a caffe espresso" becomes "an espresso coffee" or just "an espresso"; and "a caffe latte" becomes "a latte coffee" or just "a latte". It doesn't even need to be a _foreign_ phrase: you can ask for "a flat white", but it's not a kind of "white", it's short for "a flat white coffee".

Comment: Italians in the 1940s and 50s using French words? Never! :))  Back in the day, it was mostly working class people who stopped by to have an English breakfast, hot cup of tea  and takeaway sandwiches. The menu had to appeal to British palettes at the time.

Comment: @Mari-LouA What a history! :) I would absolutely welcome evidence that the word appeared elsewhere or earlier independently. The best UK menu source I can find (https://uk-menu-archives.co.uk/) usually turns up "coffee and tea," maybe with filtered coffee as a third option. But those sources may never capture boards with daily specials, offering a regular customer a *caffe latte* from the new espresso machine, and things like that.

Comment: Such shortening is obviously much more likely to happen in a user community that doesn't use the word "Latte" to mean "Milk".

Comment: With food and drink, there's a tendency for the UK to use French words where the US uses Italian: courgette vs zucchini comes to mind.

Answer (score 0):

I was listening to a BBC radio programme from the early 1960s (Something to Shout About) and one of the characters asks for a latte as though it was something very well known even by then. But bear in mind the show was set in London and written for a BBC audience, few people outside of grand hotels and Soho had probably no idea what it was

Comment: Do you know what episode? I found all of [season 1](https://archive.org/details/something-to-shout-about) online but didn't listen to it.

Comment: Assuming a reasonably sized audience, the term may have been popularised pretty quickly. OED may want to know of this reference.