# If a loan word is used with a different meaning in a given language, is it still a loan word?

Tags: loanwords

Spanish speakers use 'basket,' for basketball, 'smoking' for black tie and 'freaki' for geek. They also use 'camping' for camp site and 'parking' for car park, but the participles retain the same meaning. The latter are loan words, but I wonder whether it's accurate to use the term 'loan word' if that word undergoes a significant shift in meaning.

Comment: This question is about the word 'loanword' in English and is definitely on-topic here. But since the area of concern is in lexical semantics, you might also want to ask over at [linguistics.se] for more detailed technical answer. (Also, you may want to give examples of borrowings the other direction,  into English rather than into Spanish.

Comment: Also note that the word 'loanword' is a calque (ie an item by item translation of a foreign language term into native constituents) and 'calque' is a loanword (a borrowing directly from a foreign language.

Comment: @Mitch It might be on-topic if evidence were shown indicating that at least one dictionary doesn't give a definition allowing for loanwords to be morphologically near-identical but have an adapted meaning.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It's already ontopic. It's about what the word 'loanword' means in English. Very ontopic. That was the point of my first comment, in order to mitigate the plague of 'itchy close voting'.

Comment: Some basic research is mandatory (e.g. what definitions have you looked up and are you using?).

Comment: The Japanese language has many loan words which sometimes take on very different meanings than what it had originally. They call these "和製英語" (waseieigo), which means "Japanese-made English words" or similar (Japanglish)

Comment: I'd guess most loanwords mean something different in English to the native language, or are used with either expanded or restricted meanings. Mufti, angst, latte, café, Kindergarten, Gestalt, opera, aa, maven, tycoon, agenda...

Comment: @Mitch
 'On topic' is listed as having the synonym 'felicitous': conforming to certain standards. NOT wide of the mark. Joachim spells out the ELU requirement not fulfilled. I don't understand why people don't apply the rules. If the question has merit, and one wishes to keep it open, fine ... but research should be edited in.

Comment: Doesn't the Question Answer itself with 'significant' shift in meaning. Doesn't that depend on whether the original link remains clear?

Aren't 'smoking' for black tie and even 'freaki' for geek way of course?

Comment: Related:[Term for shortening foreign phrases in a way that would be absurd in the language of their origin](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/525211/).

Answer (score 1):

In popular parlance, "loan words" can't be distinguished from non-loan words. Every word in English is either descended from a word in some dead language, say Old English, or descended from a word in some **other** dead language, like Classical Latin. Not that much difference, really. We use the words we do because they're the words our parents used.

There are differences, but there are different kinds of loan, too. Depends on the immediate context, as well as the meaning transfers if any. Some words are just too distant to be clear, like *quintescence, pentacle,* and *Panjab*, which all come from the [PIE root for "5"](https://websites.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/penkwe.pdf). It took a long time to figure this out, and a lot of regular sound changes became evident along the way.

As for the meanings, as soon as a word is used by a speaker in another language, in whatever meaning they use it, it takes on a new life in that language, and its origin will often be forgotten, except by specialists, if they ever notice it. In other words, meaning is one of the first things lost in loan words, and if it's a loan word, its current meaning is irrelevant -- language changes independently.

Comment: In general I agree. But there is a phase where the native speakers of the country (more than language) that has borrowed a word think it has the same meaning in the original language. For example, when I lived in Germany in the early eighties I had difficulty in convincing people that in Britain we referred to “hitchhiking“ and that “autostop” was never used for this and would not be understood. This can last a long time, most Britons who are familiar with the word think “cul de sac” is used for what the French signpost “sans issue”.

Answer (score 0):

According to this source, [Oxford Academic](https://academic.oup.com/edited-volume/38609/chapter-abstract/334736644?redirectedFrom=fulltext), one should talk of *lexical borrowing* instead of loanword.

> The transmission from one language to another of a label with which to name a concept is known as ‘lexical borrowing’, and it constitutes the commonest form of contact-induced linguistic change. The items in question are often referred to as ‘loanwords’ and are said to be ‘borrowed’; both terms are erroneous.

Comment: It seems to me that these terms are based on flawed metaphors. Borrowed/loaned items are expected to be returned.

Comment: @Barmar No doubt, they are misnomers, but the language is stuck with them (at least for some while to come).

Comment: This doesn't explain the difference between "borrowing" and a "loan" in this context. It says to use *borrowing* but also says that "borrowed" is erroneous.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Maybe Oxford is admitting the same thing I pointed out -- the words are never returned.

Comment: @Barmar so was Shakespeare's Mark Antony promising to give back everyone's ears after he was done with them?

Comment: @phoog Good point. "lend an ear" is an idiom. But then, so is "lexical borrowing", it's just confined to the linguistic community. I'm not sure why LPH says one is preferred over the other; the Oxford quote says that both are erroneous, not that either is worse.